# Azure Synapse Spark LIVY_JOB_STATE_ERROR

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse, livy

i'm experimenting the following error when executing any cell in my notebook:

> LIVY_JOB_STATE_ERROR: Livy session has failed. Session state: Killed. Error code: LIVY_JOB_STATE_ERROR. [(my.synapse.spark.pool.name) WorkspaceType: CCID:<(hexcode)>] [Monitoring] Livy Endpoint=[https://hubservice1.westeurope.azuresynapse.net:8001/api/v1.0/publish/8dda5837-2f37-4a5d-97b9-0994b59e17f0]. Livy Id=[3]  Job failed during run time with state=[error]. Source: Dependency.

My notebook was working ok till yesterday, the thing that i changed is the spark pool that was using spark 2.4 to spark 3.2(preview). Such change was made by a terraform template deploy, could this be the source of the issue? if so how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed by deleting and creating my spark pool again via the azure portal, still not sure what configuration inside my terraform template created the issue but at least this fixes the problem for now.